# Why is 远 in ...与全球远作相结合的阶段?

Tags: grammar

The subject is ‘跨国公司进入一个新的市场’

第三是企业的标准化阶段，与全球远作相结合的阶段。

I think '相‘ is '互相‘
My guess is 远 works with 作:远作 = ‘remotely do'

The third stage is company standardization stage, mutually(互相） combining with （company）global operations stage.

Answer (score 6):

It must be 与全球运作相结合的阶段。
远作，there is no this compound word.

Answer (score 4):

远作 is a misspelling. 远 is far. It should be 运作: operation. 运does not work along, it is like a root, you must combine it with some other words.
Ex: 
运动 = sport, exercise
运输 = transportation
运转 = operation specifically for machines. 
运河 = canal

You can tell from these examples that 运 is strongly related to something moves. When it is used in 远作 operation, it is used in an abstract way to emphasize the "movement" in an operation.

Also, another root explanation for 远 is luck.
Ex: 
运气 = luck
命运 = destiny

Comment: Yeah, I came to the conclusion that it must be 运，a typo!

Comment: The form of 远 and 运 is so similar and it sometimes cause confusion, especially handwriting. In traditional Chinese, it is 遠 and 運 which are quite distinctive.